# How to get the likelihood function of the following situation?

Tags: probability, density-function, likelihood, bernoulli-distribution, sufficient-statistics

Consider a population with three kinds of individuals labeled, say, $1$,
$2$, and $3$ occurring in the following proportions: $p_1$ = $p^2$; $p_2 = 2p(1-
p)$; $p_3 = (1 - p)^2 \ ,(0 < p < 1)$. In a random sample of size $n$ chosen
from this population, $n_1$ individuals have been labeled $1$, $n_2$ individuals have been labeled $2$, $n_3$ individuals have been labeled $3$, respectively $(n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = n)$. How do we get the density function and likelihood?

My process: It is like $20$ trials similar to Bernoulli. So for each person, $f_p(y)=p_1^{1(y=1)}p_2^{1(y=2)}p_3^{1(y=3)}$ where $1(y=?)$ is indicator function. Thus for likelihood, it's $L(p;y)=\prod_{i=1}^n p_1^{1(y_i=1)}p_2^{1(y_i=2)}p_3^{1(y_i=3)}=p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}p_3^{n_3}$ we can insert into $p$ to get final result.

Is my thought correct?

Comment: This is a discrete random variable and doesn't have a density. It is a special case of a trinomial distribution.

Comment: @MichaelChernick So I guess we call $f_p(y)=p_1^{1(y=1)}p_2^{1(y=2)}p_3^{1(y=3)}$ a probability mass function?

Comment: Your suggestion of $p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}p_3^{n_3}$ is okay for a general trinomial (if you don't mind leaving out the [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)) but it hasn't yet taken into account the special form here -- your $p_i$'s are all functions of $p$, as you mentioned. You should show that substitution.

Comment: @Glen_b I don't get why the constant should be here. Likelihood is a streak of fixed result where the vector $y$ is given,i.e., 3123 but not 3213, so the $\frac{n!}{n_1!*n_2!*n_3!}$ doesn't quite make sense to me here.

Comment: you observe the labels of the individuals in random order. Relabeling the categories as A,B,C, you don't distinguish ABACCA from AACBCA - they both end up as "3A's, 1B, 2C's" and that is why you have that term out the front.

Comment: I see you've been posting the same questions to more than one site. Please note that the [help/on-topic] says "*Please note, however, that cross-posting is not encouraged on SE sites. Choose one best location to post your question. Later, if it proves better suited on another site, it can be migrated.*" ... please take the opportunity to read our help.